# Is there a way to check current logged in npm user?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-start, npm-publish

Just like `npm login`, `npm logout` is there any command to see 'current logged in user'?
I am using vs-code's terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `npm whoami` to see who is currently logged in on npm, see npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-whoami